# Reordering of summation symbols

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How can I manipulate the expression $$\sum_{i=1}^m (\sum_{j=0}^n a_jx_i^j)^2$$ into $$\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^na_ja_k(\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^{j+k}) $$
This is a part of the application of least squares to polynomial regression. $m $ is the number of data points and $n$ is the degree of the polynomial. These expressions were taken from 'Numerical Analysis' 9th edition by  Richard L. Burden and  J. Douglas Faires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^m \left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_jx_i^j\right)^2$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^n a_jx_i^j a_k x_i^k$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^na_ja_k\left(\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^{j+k}\right)  $$

Reordering summation symbols in the last step is okay since these are finite sums

Comment: Can you please explain more about the introduction of the new index k?

Comment: it's because $\sum_a (u_a)^2 = \sum_a \sum_b u_a u_b$. Convince yourself by writing out a few terms. If you still don't see it, note that when there are two terms, $(v+w)^2=vv+vw+wv+ww$